# Random forest Importance of OOB and error estimate

Tags: methods, tree, analytics, random-forest

This is the summary of model which I built. I am unable to understand how good my model is and would like to know what "**OOB**" means and its significance and I would like to know how can I say that my model is predicting the outcome well

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Loan_Status ~ Dependents + ApplicantIncome +      CoapplicantIncome + LoanAmount + Credit_History + Property_Area +      NC, data = train_data) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

```
  OOB estimate of  error rate: 18.89%
```

Confusion matrix:
   N   Y class.error
N 93  99  0.51562500
Y 17 405  0.04028436

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand bootstrap aggregation, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating

Out Of Bag is the average error for each Zi( Zi = (Xi,Yi) ) calculating from prediction from the trees that do not contain Zi in their respective bootstrap sample, according to this:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html